# PHP Cookie will not set

Tags: php, cookies

I am having trouble setting and echoing out a cookie, I was wondering if you could help me out, I am relatively new to php but I can work my way around. Here is the code...

```
if (empty($_COOKIE['source'])) {
$kw = $_SESSION["keyword"];
//echo $kw;
$needle = array(
    "bomanite"
);
if (multineedle_stripos($kw, $needle) || $engineName == 'Direct' || $engineName == '') {
    // branded search, don't display lead tracking phone/email
    $source = "direct";
    $liveemail = "bomanite@bomanite.ca";
    $livephone = "<span id='bom-phone'>Call us for a Quote: (416) 800 5545</span>";
} elseif ($engineName == 'ppc') {
    $source = "ppc";
    $liveemail = "bomanite@bomanite.ca";
    $livephone = "<span id='bom-phone'>Call us for a Quote: (416) 800 5446</span>";
} else {
    $source = "organic";
    $liveemail = "bomanite@bomanite.ca";
    $livephone = "<span id='bom-phone'>Call us for a Quote: (905) 660 5545</span>";
}
    setcookie("source", $source, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30), '/', 'bomanite.cidev.info/');
    setcookie("kw", $kw, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30), '/', 'bomanite.cidev.info/');
setcookie("liveemail", $liveemail,time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30), '/', 'bomanite.cidev.info/');
setcookie("livephone", $livephone,time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30), '/', 'bomanite.cidev.info/');
} else {
$source = $_COOKIE['source'];
$kw     = $_COOKIE["kw"];
$liveemail = $_COOKIE['liveemail'];
$livephone = $_COOKIE['livephone'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are very sensitive to path.. Can you try this?

```
setcookie("source", $source, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30), '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no other output to the client before the `setcookie()` call. Because it uses HTTP headers, no output can precede it.

This may be a typo in your question, but you need an opening `<?php` tag at the top of your file.